# Is Subscription automatically cleaned up after value resolved?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I was looking through some code and found this:

```
this.busy = this.service.getInfo().subscribe((info: InfoData[]) => {
            this.setInfo(info);
        });
```

Now `busy` is a component's property of type `boolean` which is used as input value for `[ngBusy]` directive. Obviously, `subscribe()` returns a `Subscription`, which is not null and therefore is cast to `true`. This triggers directive to show modal loading popup, which goes away once info is resolved. That means, that `this.busy` is false by that moment, which I have to mean that `Subscription` object exists no more.

Inside `getInfo()` method there is only one line, which is `return Observable.of(info)`, where info is stub variable.

**So my question is:**
Is `Subscription` deleted automatically right after data is resolved? If yes, is it only for `Observable.of()` or are there any other examples of such behavior?

Comment: check this SO question it discusseds in detail about cleaning up subscriptions, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular2-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription

Comment: in this case yeah

Comment: Some subscription are automatically cleaned up, such as those used with the Http service and those used with Routing. All of the others need to be unsubscribed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is Subscription deleted automatically right after data is resolved?

**No, it is not.** - The subscription-object will still exist, which is due to the fact, that in JavaScript an object cannot "remove itself". You can also check the code below, to see that there is still a subscription-object. It is not attached to the stream any more but it still exists.

I'm assuming, that you are using [angular2-busy](https://github.com/devyumao/angular2-busy) - if that is the case, then you should take a closer look at the documentation - `[ngBusy]` is capable of evaluating a subscription-object and will stop showing the busy-indication when that subscription-object is *closed*.

---

In the code-sample below you can see that by the end of the subscription, it will still exist, but in a non-operational/closed state - [angular2-busy](https://github.com/devyumao/angular2-busy) is able to detect this.

```js
const of$ = Rx.Observable.of("Test");

let sub = of$.subscribe();

// the subscription will be automatically closed, but not be "undefined" or "falsly"
console.log(sub);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```